# I want to group by my dataframe at two different levels before converting into json format

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have data frame with below structure and data. I want to group by at 2 different levels: `level1` by `doc_id` and `doc_name`, and `level2 pgf_id pgf_data`. After doing the `groupby`, this need to be converted to json in the below format.

```
df_final = (df.groupby(['pgf_id'], as_index=True)
    .apply(lambda x: x[['sent_id','sent_data','label']].to_dict('r'))
    .reset_index().to_json(orient='records'))

doc_id  doc_name    pgf_id  pgf_data    sent_id sent_data   label
001abz  simple_doc  0001567a This is for understanding purpose. There are more 2 important sentences in the para.
```

```
 {
    "doc_id": "001abz",
    "doc_name": "simple_doc",
    "paragraphs": [
        {
            "pgf_id": "0001567a",
            "pgf_text": "This is for understanding purpose. There are more 2 important sentences in the para."
            {
              "sent_id": "0" 
              "sent_data": "This is for understanding purpose".
              "label" : "label1"

             },
             {
              "sent_id": "1" 
              "sent_data": "There are more 2 important sentences in the para.".
              "label" : "label2"

             }

        },
        {
            "pgf_id": "0001999a",
            "pgf_text": "This is a different para that need to be classified. The extraction is a part of it. Extraction is done for multiple sentences. "
             {
              "sent_id": "0" 
              "sent_data": "This is a different para that need to be classified".
              "label" : "label2"

             },
             {
              "sent_id": "1" 
              "sent_data": "The extraction is a part of it."
              "label" : "label1"

             },
             {
              "sent_id": "2" 
              "sent_data": "Extraction is done for multiple sentences. "
              "label" : "label3"

             }
        }
      ]

}
```

Comment: Your post is complete broken. Please fix it to make sense.

Comment: I have fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not sure if you meant to post valid JSON or some variant, but I made a few assumptions about it, mainly that the bare objects with keys `sent_id` etc. were meant to be in an array, with key `r`.  If you are okay with using some loops, here's what I did:

```
from json import dumps

# `df` is a pandas.DataFrame with your data

output = []
for (doc_id, doc_name), pgf_dataframe in df.groupby(['doc_id', 'doc_name']):
    document = {'doc_id': doc_id, 'doc_name': doc_name}
    paragraphs = []
    for (pgf_id, pgf_data), r_dataframe in pgf_dataframe.groupby(['pgf_id', 'pgf_data']):
        paragraph = {'pgf_id': pgf_id, 'pgf_text': pgf_data}
        events = []
        for i, row in r_dataframe.iterrows():
            events.append({'sent_id': row['sent_id'], 'sent_data': row['sent_data'], 'label': row['label']})
        paragraph['r'] = events
        paragraphs.append(paragraph)
    document['paragraphs'] = paragraphs
    output.append(document)

# `output` is a list of "document" objects.
print(dumps(output))
```